# Give a rectangle a different colors while animating using raphaeljs

Tags: javascript, raphael

This code is expected to animate the rectangle bottom up and at the same time switching colors from black to red infinitely. But it always used a single color i.e. red instead of black and then red.

```
var spec = { width: 23, height: 190, x: 8, y: 0, r : 5}
var speed = 2000;

var rect1 = paper.rect(spec.x, spec.height, PatientBar1.width, 0, spec.r);

function animateRaphaelRect(){
    rect1.attr({y:spec.height,height:0})
    rect1.animate(
        {fill: 'black', stroke:'#000', y:spec.y, height:spec.height},
        speed
    );
    rect1.animate(
        {fill: 'red', stroke:'#000', y:spec.y, height:spec.height},
        speed,
        function(){
            animateRaphaelRect();
        }
    );
}
animateRaphaelRect();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are doing two animations on the same object at once. Instead try setting the start state first and not as an animation, like this... [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sUn6h/1/)

```
var paper = Raphael("container");

var spec = { width: 23, height: 190, x: 8, y: 0, r : 5}
var speed = 2000;

var rect1 = paper.rect(spec.x, spec.height, 400, 0, spec.r);

function animateRaphaelRect(){
    rect1.attr({y:spec.height,height:0})

    rect1.animate(
        {fill: 'red', stroke:'#000', y:spec.y, height:spec.height},
        speed,
        function(){
            rect1.attr("fill", "black");
            animateRaphaelRect();
        }
    );
}
animateRaphaelRect();
```